# Fractal dimension of domain wall in Ising model at criticality

Tags: measure-theory, fractals, statistical-mechanics

Consider the Ising model on an $L \times L$ lattice with periodic boundary conditions in the east/west directions and with spins on the north boundary fixed as $+1$ and the spins on the south boundary fixed as $-1$. Then, if you fix a cold temperature $T < T_c$, as $L \to \infty$ you expect that the domain wall between the $+1$ spin cluster on the top and the $-1$ spin cluster on the bottom approaches a flat line (dimension 1), and exactly at $T = T_c$ you expect there to be some nontrivial behaviour, where you end up with the domain wall being some fractal dimension between $1$ and $2$.

This is just intuition I've gleaned from a talk I attended ~2 years ago, but I can't find any references following this line of thought. Are there any places to look to see experiments in this direction? In particular, I'm mainly curious how to rigorously define what the fractal dimension we are measuring at $T = T_c$ is in the thermodynamic limit, and what this number turns out to be.

As an example of how to formalise what I'm talking about, we can consider the box-counting dimension, and simply define the fractal dimension of the domain wall to be:
$$\text{dim}_\text{box}(\text{Domain Wall}) = \lim_{\epsilon = \frac{1}{L} \to 0} \frac{\langle\text{Number of sites that the domain wall passes through}\rangle_\text{Gibbs Distribution on L x L lattice}}{\log(1/\epsilon)}$$
There might be other formulations based on the actual thermodynamic limit measure, but this isn't something I'm too familiar with

Comment: From a google I found this https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2013-26-04/S0894-0347-2013-00774-2/S0894-0347-2013-00774-2.pdf which seems to use a phrase called ‘Ising interface’

Comment: It is known (for various kinds of boundary conditions, although I don't know whether the precise setup you mention has explicitly been studied) that the scaling limit of a critical Ising interface is given by an SLE(3) process (see, for instance, [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.0533)). In turn, the curve of an SLE($\kappa$) process with $\kappa\geq 0$ has almost surely a Hausdorff dimension equal to $\min(2, 1+\kappa/8)$ (see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0211322)). So for a critical Ising interface, you get $11/8$.